# Access Contol Apache 2.4: Require all denied not working

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server

I turned off access_compat module and changed all Order directives to Require in order to comply Apache 2.4 requirements.

My public virtual hosts still working fine. But I get "Require all denied" not working when I test it. Everybody has access to site.

In apache2.config:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In virtual host file:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/my.site
ServerName my.site

    <Directory />
        Require all denied

        AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .php

        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </Directory>
```

I've read all Apache help on "Require" and tried everithing I could imagine. Please help.

Apache version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)